# script to validate birthdate

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I got this script

```
 $("#SocialSecurityNumber").attr("placeholder","YYYY-MM-DD-XXXX").blur(function () {
        var str = $('#SocialSecurityNumber').val();
        var res = /^([1-2]\d{3})\-([0-1][1-9])\-([0-3][0-9])\-([0-9]{4})$/.exec(str);
        var todays_date = new Date();
        var birth_date = new Date(res[1], res[2], res[3]);

        if (todays_date - birth_date > 565633905872) {
            $("#btn-activation").removeAttr('disabled');
            $("#SocialSecurityNumber").removeClass("input-validation-error");
        } else {
            $("#SocialSecurityNumber").attr("placeholder","Please enter date of birth as YYYY-MM-DD-XXXX").addClass("input-validation-error");
            $("#btn-activation").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });

});
```

Which will validate age, from input #SocialSecurityNumber
However, when entering letters or other jibberish it doesnt validate at all and i get js error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
```

Could somone help me with how i can add so this script also validates incorrect characters? (when regex is not matched)

Comment: If the RegEx doesn't match, `res` will be null... so calling the index on it will always fail.  You need to test for `res != null` (or similar) before doing `res[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, in javascript, if the RegEx does not match, then the result is `null`.

Therefore you are attempting to index a `null` variable... which is why you're seeing the error.

You need to check for a `null` value, with something like this...

```
 var res = /^([1-2]\d{3})\-([0-1][1-9])\-([0-3][0-9])\-([0-9]{4})$/.exec(str);
 var todays_date = new Date();
 var birth_date = null;
 if (res != null) {
   birth_date = new Date(res[1], res[2], res[3]);
 }

 if (birth_date == null || todays_date - birth_date > 565633905872) {
    ...
```

You'll need to sort out the exact logic yourself, but hopefully this gives you an idea of what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no match, then `res` will be `null`. So one thing which you can do is:

```
if(res.length==3)
var birth_date = new Date(res[1], res[2], res[3]);
```

This confirms that you get only right number of matches.